# Copy/remove characters "in place" without causing UB from strcpy

Tags: performance, c, c11

I am writing a portable library function, which is a generic "remove characters" function. Language standards used are C11 and MISRA-C:2012.

TL;DR: it should either remove all occurrences of a specific character in the beginning of a string, or it should remove all occurrences of the specific character no matter where they are in the string.

The detailed specification:

```
void remove_ch (char*        str_trimmed, 
                const char*  str_untrimmed,
                char         ch,
                bool         initial_only);

/*
   DESCRIPTION          Copies the string [str_untrimmed] into the string [str_trimmed],
                        save for all characters of value [ch]. If the flag [initial_only]
                        is set, only occurrences of [ch] in the very beginning of the 
                        string will be removed.

   PRE_CONDITION        [str_trimmed] should point at an allocated buffer that is at
                        least the same size as [str_untrimmed].

   POST_CONDITION       None

   PARAMETERS

     [str_trimmed]      A pointer to an allocated buffer of at least the same size as
                        [str_untrimmed].
     [str_untrimmed]    A pointer to the string that will be copied.
     [ch]               The character to remove.
     [initial_only]     If set to true, characters of value [ch] will only be removed if 
                        they are found in the very beginning of the string.
                        If set to false, all characters value [ch] will be
                        removed, no matter where they are in the string.

   RETURNS              -
*/
```

Additionally, and this is important, I wish to be able to use the function "in place". That is, `str_trimmed` is potentially pointing at the very same address as `str_untrimmed`.

---

My code, including a test case (tested with GCC 4.9.1/Mingw64):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void remove_ch (char*        str_trimmed, 
                const char*  str_untrimmed,
                char         ch,
                bool         initial_only)
{
  if(initial_only)
  {
    while(*str_untrimmed != '\0' && *str_untrimmed == ch)
    {
      str_untrimmed++;
    }

    while(*str_untrimmed != '\0')
    {
      *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
      str_trimmed++;
      str_untrimmed++;
    }
    *str_trimmed = '\0';
  }
  else
  {
    while(*str_untrimmed != '\0')
    {
      if(*str_untrimmed != ch)
      {
        *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
        str_trimmed++;
      }
      str_untrimmed++;
    }
    *str_trimmed = '\0';
  }
}


int main (void)
{
  char hello [] = "  hello hello world !";

  remove_ch(hello, hello, ' ', true);
  puts(hello); // should give "hello hello world !"

  remove_ch(hello, hello, ' ', false);
  puts(hello); // should give "hellohelloworld!"

  remove_ch(hello, hello, 'l', false);
  puts(hello); // should give "heoheoword!"
}
```

---

My concern is performance. I have not yet attempted any manual optimizations.

Rather the contrary... Particularly, I'm not pleased with this part, which is a manually-implemented `strcpy`:

```
while(*str_untrimmed != '\0')
{
  *str_trimmed = *str_untrimmed;
  str_trimmed++;
  str_untrimmed++;
}
*str_trimmed = '\0';
```

Instead of this, I initially had a call to `strcpy()`, which will supposedly be nicely optimized for the specific hardware. The problem with that though, is that both parameters of strcpy() are `restrict` pointers and my requirement is that I should be able to call `remove_ch` "in place".

In the special case where the user passes a string with no initial characters matching `ch`, I would end up with something equal to `strcpy(ptr, ptr)` which invokes undefined behavior, as it violates the `restrict` contract with `strcpy`.

In order to dodge that bug, I rolled out my own `strcpy`.

The above issue is my main concern which I would like some feedback on.

---

As for the rest of the code and overall hardware concerns: this code will be widely ported between various smaller, single-core microcontroller embedded systems. I believe the number of instructions is the main performance concern, then program size. Things like improving branch prediction are likely not a very important concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial code:

```
if(initial_only)
  {
    while(*str_untrimmed != '\0' && *str_untrimmed == ch)
```

the test for `*str_untrimmed != '\0'` is redundant. Also, I would reduce the names `str_untrimmed` and `str_trimmed` to `src` and `dest` to make it clearer.

More significantly, there are really two applications: remove leading characters and remove embedded characters. I see no reason to combine them into one function. Unless there is a strong reason against, I would write separate functions: `remove_leading_ch` and `remove_ch`.

If this is to be used to strip leading spaces (and tabs etc), it might be more useful to take a set of chars to remove:

```
void remove_leading (char* dest, const char* src, char* chrs)
{
    src += strspn(src, chrs);

    for (; *src != '\0'; ++src, ++dest) {
        *dest = *src;
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

It would also be normal to return, for example, the start address of the destination string.

Comment: Good suggestions, making two functions will also make the caller interface more simple, so I think I'll go with that.

Answer (score 1):

This might not make much of a difference (since the compiler could probably make this optimization) but I would replace all your postfix increments with prefix increments. This will prevent you from creating a whole bunch of copies of `char`s.

Also, it might be worth it to implement a non-`restrict` `strcpy` of your own and call it within your function (just for code clarity purposes).

```
void non_restrict_strcpy(const char *a, const char *b)
{
  // ...
}
```

A final suggestion I have would be to implement a `restrict` version of your `remove_ch` function. Then, have that one call the standard `strcpy`. This way, you have two functions; one for when you know that there is no pointer aliasing and one where there is pointer aliasing.

Also, out of curiosity, did you benchmark your performance and see if you even needed to make it faster?

Comment: "but I would replace all your postfix increments with prefix increments. This will prevent you from creating a whole bunch of copies of char" Huh? The increments are on lines of their own, so I don't see how this would matter? It will not increase performance. Regarding making two versions it would make sense if I could somehow programmatically check if a certain compiler implements pointer aliasing, with `#ifdef` compiler switches. But I don't think that is possible? I haven't benchmarked or made attempts to optimize it yet, but it is library code so it will need to be as tight as possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "if a compiler implements pointer aliasing"? Pointer aliasing is simply when two pointers are pointing to the same memory so I'm not sure how that's a compiler implementation. Usage of the `restrict` keyword is a contract you sign with the  compiler like you mentioned before. What I meant is, create another restricted version of your function and document in your API that if you don't plan on using the `remove_ch` function in place, then you should use the restricted version.

Answer (score 0):

Edited, to comply with latest version of requirement:

The usual method, which should work anywhere (but I have not tested it on big Endian architecture), is to have two pointers (parameters 1 and 2 could be used).

- Loop until NUL byte is encountered

  - If source `char` allowed into destination

    - Assigned to `dest` pointer
    - increment destination pointer
  - End if
  - Increment source pointer
- End loop
- Set the string terminator byte

The following code:

1. Cleanly compiles
2. Does not need an `#include <stdio.h>`
3. Does the desired function
4. Uses 'minimal' code space
5. Has a reasonably fast execution time

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void remove_ch (char*        str_trimmed,
                const char*  str_untrimmed,
                char         ch,
                bool         initial_only)
{

    int dIndex = 0;
    for( int sIndex=0; str_untrimmed[sIndex]; sIndex++)
    {

        if( initial_only && !dIndex  && str_untrimmed[sIndex] != ch ) 
        {
            str_trimmed[dIndex] = str_untrimmed[sIndex];
            dIndex++;
        }

        else if( initial_only && dIndex )
        {
            str_trimmed[dIndex] = str_untrimmed[sIndex];
            dIndex++;
        }

        else if( !initial_only && str_untrimmed[sIndex] != ch )
        {
           str_trimmed[dIndex] = str_untrimmed[sIndex];
           dIndex++;
        }
    }
    str_trimmed[dIndex] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: This only removes the first occurrence of `ch` if  `initial_only == true`. The OP's code removes all occurrences of `ch` at the head of the string.

Comment: the OPs question stated that if 'initial_only' is true, to only remove a leading char, not every occurrence of the char,  However, if 'initial_only' is false to remove all occurrences of the char.  (at least that is my understanding of the question.)

Comment: The specification might be a bit unclear I guess. It should remove all occurrences of a certain character from the beginning of a string. For example if you have string with digits "000123" and wish to print it as "123". Check my test case with comments containing the expected output.

Comment: given the clarification, this line: `if( (initial_only && sIndex > 0 ) || str_untrimmed[sIndex] != ch)`  needs to be modified

Answer (score 0):

Combining the suggestions made by Bizkit and William Morris, I ended up splitting the function in two, one that removes all occurrences and one that only removes leading occurrences.

To solve the restrict issue, the "remove leading" version calls a `custom_strcpy` in the case where there were no initial characters found. The custom strcpy is defined as:

`char* custom_strcpy (char* s1, const char* s2);`

Code:

```
void remove_ch (char* dest, const char* src, char ch)
{
  while(*src != '\0')
  {
    if(*src != ch)
    {
      *dest = *src;
      src++;
    }
    dest++;
  }

  *dest = '\0';
}


void remove_ch_leading (char* dest, const char* src, char ch)
{
  while(*src == ch)
  {
    src++;
  }

  if(src == dest)
  {
    custom_strcpy(dest, src); // non-restrict pointers
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(dest, src); // restrict pointer + highly optimized
  }
}
```